# Separate a string into a column by character and numbers in R

Tags: r

I have this list that contain different strings:

portfolio:

```
[[1]]
[1] "BANK       Percentage"

[[2]]
[1] "JP MORGAN     16.93%"

[[3]]
[1] "BNP PARIBAS      14.29%"

[[4]]
[1] "JAPAN POST BANK    13.96%"

[[5]]
[1] "Sumitomo Mitsui Banking   9.80%"

[[6]]
[1] "Banco Santander  8.67%"

[[7]]
[1] "Deutsche Bank  6.26%"

[[8]]
[1] "CITIBANK  6.23%"

[[9]]
[1] "Barclays Bank  4.84%"

[[10]]
[1] "Royal Bank of Canada 4.38%"

[[11]]
[1] "Postal Savings Bank of China Co Ltd 4.22%"
```

I was splitting this strings in two columns with this code:

```
portfolio <- lapply(portfolio, str_split, pattern = "  ", n = 2, simplify = T)
portfolio <- do.call(rbind, portfolio)
```

How you can see, I was splitting by two spaces as a pattern and then I obtain a matrix with two columns but, the last two objects disappear because have these only one space between characters and numbers so this don´t work.

Guys help me, please.

Comment: It can help a lot when your question is formatted such that code is preformatted text, etc; I suggest you quickly look at https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```r
portfolio <- list(
"BANK       Percentage",
"JP MORGAN     16.93%",
"BNP PARIBAS      14.29%",
"JAPAN POST BANK    13.96%",
"Sumitomo Mitsui Banking   9.80%",
"Banco Santander  8.67%",
"Deutsche Bank  6.26%",
"CITIBANK  6.23%",
"Barclays Bank  4.84%",
"Royal Bank of Canada 4.38%",
"Postal Savings Bank of China Co Ltd 4.22%")
gre <- gregexpr("[.0-9%]+", portfolio[-1])
pct <- regmatches(portfolio[-1], gre)
pct <- unlist(replace(pct, sapply(pct, is.null), NA))
nm <- trimws(sapply(regmatches(portfolio[-1], gre, invert = TRUE), `[[`, 1))

data.frame(BANK = nm, Percentage = pct, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
#                                   BANK Percentage
# 1                            JP MORGAN     16.93%
# 2                          BNP PARIBAS     14.29%
# 3                      JAPAN POST BANK     13.96%
# 4              Sumitomo Mitsui Banking      9.80%
# 5                      Banco Santander      8.67%
# 6                        Deutsche Bank      6.26%
# 7                             CITIBANK      6.23%
# 8                        Barclays Bank      4.84%
# 9                 Royal Bank of Canada      4.38%
# 10 Postal Savings Bank of China Co Ltd      4.22%
```

Comment: Thanks!! A interesting way to resolve the problem. :D

Answer (score 2):

We can exploit the `data.table::tstrsplit` function and the regex look behind Perl flavour. Using the `portfolio` object defined by @r2evans, you can try:

```
require(data.table)
setNames(data.frame(
           tstrsplit(unlist(portfolio)[-1],"\\s+(?=[0-9])",perl=TRUE)
                   ),
           strsplit(portfolio[[1]],"\\s+")[[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

The code below should work for you. It uses a more complex split pattern leveraging regex. `(\\s{2,}|\\s(?=[0-9]))`, so that it splits any characters if there are more than two spaces (`\\s{2,}`), or (`|`), a single space if it is followed by a number (`\\s(?=[0-9])`). This could still get tricked if the bank name had a number in it (eg "Bank 3  5.67%") will cause it to fail.

```r
library(stringr)

dat <- 
  list(c("BANK       Percentage"),
       c("JP MORGAN     16.93%"),
       c("BNP PARIBAS      14.29%"),
       c("JAPAN POST BANK    13.96%"),
       c("Sumitomo Mitsui Banking   9.80%"),
       c("Banco Santander  8.67%"),
       c("Deutsche Bank  6.26%"),
       c("CITIBANK  6.23%"),
       c("Barclays Bank  4.84%"),
       c("Royal Bank of Canada 4.38%"),
       c("Postal Savings Bank of China Co Ltd 4.22%"))

portfolio <- 
  lapply(dat, str_split, "(\\s{2,}|\\s(?=[0-9]))", n = 2, simplify = TRUE)

portfolio <- do.call(rbind, portfolio)

portfolio
#>       [,1]                                  [,2]        
#>  [1,] "BANK"                                "Percentage"
#>  [2,] "JP MORGAN"                           "16.93%"    
#>  [3,] "BNP PARIBAS"                         "14.29%"    
#>  [4,] "JAPAN POST BANK"                     "13.96%"    
#>  [5,] "Sumitomo Mitsui Banking"             "9.80%"     
#>  [6,] "Banco Santander"                     "8.67%"     
#>  [7,] "Deutsche Bank"                       "6.26%"     
#>  [8,] "CITIBANK"                            "6.23%"     
#>  [9,] "Barclays Bank"                       "4.84%"     
#> [10,] "Royal Bank of Canada"                "4.38%"     
#> [11,] "Postal Savings Bank of China Co Ltd" "4.22%"
```

<sup>Created on 2020-04-13 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: This works great!! Have another lists and it's perfect. Thank u so much!